# Windows Home Server backup recovery missing driver for USB Device

Tags: backup-restoration, windows-home-server

I'm doing a backup recovery of a Windows 7 PC from the backup on Windows Home Server.  I've done this before and am accustomed to the prompt to load drivers for devices such as the NIC from a USB flash drive, which I have all loaded up with the drivers from the special folder in the WHS backup repository for this PC.

My problem on this PC is that one of the drivers the recovery CD complains is missing is "USB Device", and it fails to find the drivers when I click the button to scan for and install drivers.  So it seems it can't access the USB flash drive to load the other drivers.

Any suggestions?

I think my next step is to pull a DVD drive from another system and plug it in with a CD burned with the device drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arggh, the problem wasn't missing USB drivers.  The problem was that the WHS recovery process would not recognize the drivers from the special folder in the WHS backup repository for this PC.  When I put drivers manually downloaded from the motherboard manufacturer onto the USB flash drive, it all worked.  So I guess you can't trust the drivers that WHS keeps for recovery purposes.